# Quel est le nom du métier de la personne qui vous donne un ticket dans un bus ?

Tags: expressions

J'ai longtemps cherché ce nom, pouvez-vous m'aider ?

Answer (score 4):

Ce métier n'existe plus de nos jours. Auparavant cette personne était appelée « Receveur. »

Comment: Ce métier n'existe plus en France (ni en Belgique) mais existe peut-être encore ailleurs ? D'ailleurs en Belgique il semble que le terme ne soit pas encore totalement abandonné : https://www.infotec.be/fr-be/jobs/postulerautec/offresdemplois/offredemploi.aspx?id=721&type=1

Comment: @LaurentS.: Probablement, je parle en tant que Français.

Comment: Le métier existe effectivement encore dans certains pays: par exemple on peut en trouver sur certaines lignes de trams à Amsterdam.

Answer (score 0):

In a bus today, the only person that will sell a ticket to you is the bus driver, whose job has for title "conducteur / conductrice d'autobus".

I hope you are not taking "ticket" in French as meaning "procès verbal", "contravention" or equivalently, "amende": this meaning of "ticket"» does not exist in French. The name of the job of those latter empoyees is "contrôlleur/contrôleuse de transport en commun", which can be shortened into "contrôleur de transport" and simply "contrôleur/contrôleuse".

Comment: In Belgium, the people checking your tickets in the trains are also commonly named "accompagnateur/accompagnatrice". Contrôleur/contrôleuse is also indeed commonly used but those people are less fond of it as they estimate their work implies much more than just "controlling" the tickets.

Comment: @LaurentS. « Accompagnateur » est un nom assez étrange ; je n'en vois pas la justification de sens par analogie autrement qu'en  se référant au fait que ces individus sont forcés de faire au moins une partie du voyage avec les personnes qu'ils sont chargés de contrôler ; c'est plutôt exagéré comme justification pour utiliser ce mot.

Comment: Je pense que le terme est issu de la mode du politiquement correct. Je pense également qu'il se rapporte plus à l'accompagnement du train que celui des passagers, en effet ce sont aussi eux qui assurent l'ouverture et la fermeture des portes, qui donnent le signal du départ, qui communiquent les arrêts, les éventuels retards, etc. Donc le terme "contrôleur" est effectivement réducteur, mais il est vrai que le terme "accompagnateur" n'est guère utilisé qu'en Belgique...

Comment: @LaurentS. Dans ce sens le terme devient assez raisonnable, il me semble.